# Why did this stopped working ? Android with mysqli

Tags: php, android, mysql

SOLUTION:for anyone having similar problems  After playing around a lot I though of re-creating the project as last resort. so I made a new project and transferred my code there.   It did the trick. I dont know why it worked but it did

Hello I have this codes here. when I am using the app it was suppose the send the data in to the database,it was doing that just fine but it somehow stopped. 
I have checked and changed the IP address I am using

EDIT: I have tried to add data to the database using "Postman" and it actually added the values in the database. but the problem with the app still remains. I have not changed a single line since my last test. but somehow the app does not even try to send the data

Android APP code

MainActivity.java

```
        package com.example.chara.crashcontrol;

    import android.provider.Settings; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.util.Base64; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.CheckBox; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError; import com.android.volley.Request; import com.android.volley.RequestQueue; import com.android.volley.Response; import com.android.volley.VolleyError; import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest; import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException; import java.util.HashMap; import java.util.Map;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button btnShowLocation;
        GPStracker gps;
        EditText firstname,num,plate;
        RequestQueue requestQueue;
        CheckBox scene,traped,ambulance;
        private String scene_is_checked = "no";
        private String traped_is_checked = "no";
        private String ambulance_is_checked ="no";
        private String lat,lon;
        String insertUrl = "http://MY_IP(censored)/storedata.php";
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            firstname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
            num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
            plate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.plate);
            scene = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.scene);
            traped = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.traped);
            ambulance = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ambulance);
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);


            btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    gps = new GPStracker(MainActivity.this);
                    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                     double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                         lat = Double.toString(latitude);
                     lon = Double.toString(longitude);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is =\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();




                    } else {
                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    }


                    if (ambulance.isChecked()){
                        ambulance_is_checked ="Yes";

                    }
                    if (scene.isChecked()) {
                        scene_is_checked = "Yes";
                    }
                    if (traped.isChecked()){
                        traped_is_checked = "Yes";

                    }

                    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            System.out.println(response.toString());
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }) {

                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                          String  e_fristname = firstname.getText().toString();
                            String efirstname = Base64.encodeToString(e_fristname.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                            String e_nums = num.getText().toString();
                            String e_numb = Base64.encodeToString(e_nums.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                            String e_plate = plate.getText().toString();
                            String eplate = Base64.encodeToString(e_plate.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                            String e_scene = scene_is_checked.toString();
                            String escene = Base64.encodeToString(e_scene.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                            String e_traped = traped_is_checked.toString();
                            String etraped = Base64.encodeToString(e_traped.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                            String e_ambulance = ambulance_is_checked.toString();
                            String eambulance = Base64.encodeToString(e_ambulance.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                            lat="43.232153";
                            lon="65.213422";
                            Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            parameters.put("firstname", efirstname.toString());
                            parameters.put("num", e_numb.toString());
                            parameters.put("plate",eplate.toString());
                            parameters.put("scene", escene.toString());
                            parameters.put("traped", etraped.toString());
                            parameters.put("ambulance",eambulance.toString());
                            parameters.put("lat",lat.toString());
                            parameters.put("lon", lon.toString());
                            btnShowLocation.setEnabled(false);
                            return parameters;



                        }
                    };
                    requestQueue.add(request);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(9000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    btnShowLocation.setEnabled(true);

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();
                }

        });
    }
}
```

GetGPSlocation.Java (I did not make this but it works)

```
package com.example.chara.crashcontrol;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class GPStracker  extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context context;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 9000;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPStracker(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);


            if(!isGPSEnabled && !isGPSEnabled) {

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if(isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);


                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        }
                    }
                }
                if(isGPSEnabled) {
                    if(location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        if(locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if(location != null){
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return location;
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPStracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS SETTINGS");

        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled.Go to Settings menu and enable it?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }) ;
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

PHP Code

connection.php

```
<?php


define('hostname', 'myip(censored)');
define('user','root');
define('password','');
define('databaseName','crashcontrol');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname , user , password ,databaseName);


?>
```

storedata.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    require 'connection.php';
    createData();


}

function createData()
{
    global $connect;
    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $num = $_POST["num"];
    $plate = $_POST["plate"];
    $scene = $_POST["scene"];
    $ambulance = $_POST["ambulance"];
    $traped = $_POST["traped"];
    $lon = $_POST["lon"];
    $lat = $_POST["lat"];


    $query = "INSERT INTO report(firstname,num,plate,scene,ambulance,traped,lon,lat) values ('$firstname','$num','$plate','$scene','$ambulance','$traped','$lon','$lat');";

    mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);



}
?>
```

My error codes from appchie and mysql

appachie

```
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:36.296359 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 12848:tid 504] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:36.407439 2016] [core:warn] [pid 12848:tid 504] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:36.633599 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 12848:tid 504] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:36.710653 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12848:tid 504] AH00455: Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:36.710653 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12848:tid 504] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Dec  9 2015 10:17:39
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:36.710653 2016] [core:notice] [pid 12848:tid 504] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:36.715157 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 12848:tid 504] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 10884
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:38.454892 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10884:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:38.771117 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 10884:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Jan 11 18:28:38.848671 2016] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10884:tid 560] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

mysql

```
2016-01-11 18:28:37 17d4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-01-11 18:28:37 6100 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-01-11 18:28:38 6100 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 2035625
2016-01-11 18:28:38 7364 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-01-11 18:28:38 6100 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-01-11 18:28:38 6100 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2016-01-11 18:28:38 6100 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.9-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Comment: Yow! Nether escaping post values, not using prepared statements with bind variables..... let's hope you never get a `'` in any of your data

Comment: I used to get the data I was sending normally though , but why did it stopped I cant understand that, it does not try to send something nor giving me any erros in the console

Comment: "it stopped" is pretty vague. What happened? Is the app crashing? Are there errors on the server? Do you get an error message? Is there anything in the server log file or in the app's logcat? If there are no symptoms, how do you know it isn't working? Please post some details.

Comment: I have eddied the main post with the errors in the logs if you kindly can give them a look it would be great thanks

Comment: I don't have experience with Java, but it may help to print out the error on your POST request where `public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }` and add `System.out.println(error.toString());` inside it.

Comment: I have no idea how to read that error though.